# Magento1 REST API Access Denied

Tags: apache, rest, magento-1.9

I am getting permission denied issue in 1.9 with REST API even though added all required Roles and Permissions.

Its working for guest users and getting the JSON result.

I can take customers via url api/rest/products?limit=1 without any authentication if i enabled Guest permission.
Same time its working with oAuth for a valid admin used.
But if i disabled guest permissions its not working for a valid admin user, showing the permission denied message.

When i check the access log, i can see like below

```
exception 'Mage_Api2_Exception' with message 'Access denied' in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Server.php:217
Stack trace: #0 var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Server.php(106): Mage_Api2_Model_Server->_allow(Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Request), Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Auth_User_Guest))
#1 /var/www/html/api.php(73): Mage_Api2_Model_Server->run()
```

is it because each API request via oAuth treats in Guest mode ?

Answer (score 0):

How are you testing? Are you absolutely sure that you are indeed running an authorised request when disabling guest permission?

Maybe you can do some step-by-step debug in the class method `_allow` of `Mage_Api2_Model_Server`.